# facebook module crash when using internationalisation on appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm coding a game and I'm using internationalisation. I want to share the score with the Facebook module. My code:

```
if(fb.getCanPresentShareDialog()) {
    fb.presentShareDialog({
        link: 'https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100010324151821',
        name: 'Memory Speed',
        description:String.format(L('share'), Ti.App.score),
        caption:L('caption_partage_score_facebook'),
   });
} else {
    fb.presentWebShareDialog({
        link: 'https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100010324151821',
        name: 'Memory Speed',
        description:String.format(L('share'), Ti.App.score),
        caption:L('caption_partage_score_facebook'),
    });
}.
```

`'share'`: link to my strings.xml file

`Ti.App.score`: var with the score

When I click on the share button, the app closes itself.

I tried to replace `Ti.App.score` with a string like `'hello'` and the app doesn't crash.

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Store "score" either at Globally using

```
 "Alloy.Globals.score"
```

or store it in property e.g

```
  Ti.App.Properties.setString('score', '20');
```

And use either of it...

Comment: Indeed. You should never add custom properties to any `Ti.` namespace object.